# Как замедлить выполнение SQL запроса?

Tags: sql-server

У меня странная задача... Обычно всем хочется, чтобы запросы выполнялись побыстрее — но мне в тренировочных целях (для изучения механизма работы пула соединений) нужно замедлить запрос, чтобы было нагляднее видно.

Скажем, есть абсолютно простой запрос к единственной таблице в базе данных:

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[title]
FROM [dbo].[Tasks]
```

И мне хочется, чтобы этот запрос выполнялся не мгновенно, а примерно пять секунд. (В идеале - хорошо, чтобы это время как-то можно было настроить)

Как можно сделать подобное? Желательно модификацией самого SQL-запроса, а не изменением параметров SQL сервера или настроек операционной системы. Данных в самой таблице мало — не более ста записей.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276964/how-to-slow-down-a-sql-query

Comment: Дописать в запрос WAITFOR DELAY?

Comment: @Bulson Никогда не думал, что cross join (самый бесполезный join) может пригодиться в жизни.

Comment: @PashaPash Почему не ответом? Весьма наглядный способ.

Comment: Значит вы все таки выбрали cross join, а не  WAITFOR DELAY. Интересно почему?

Comment: @Bulson Нет, я выбрал WAITFOR. А с cross join просто запомнил, что если придётся делать не под MSSQL а какую-нибудь другую систему и если там не будет такого, то уж кросс джойн точно будет т.к. он будет на любой ANSI-92 совместимой системе. Ну и -- просто любопытный кейс, никогда не думал, что он может пригодиться в жизни.

Comment: OK. Понял......

Comment: Может замедление лучше делать на стороне клиента, а не сервера? Я бы лучше в Read-цикл Sleep бы вставил. Тормозить сам SQL - можно при неккуратном использование deathlock-ов нахватать.

Answer (score 1):

Заверни запрос в процедуру

```
create procedure slowQuery
as
begin
  waitfor delay '000:00:20' -- 20 sec
  SELECT [id]
      ,[title]
  FROM [dbo].[Tasks]
end
```

и потом вызывай процедуру

Answer (score 0):

Огромный блоб загрузи в бд =) Или какой-либо иной огромный файл. Чем больше он весит, тем больше будет выполняться запрос.
Возможно есть другие способы, мне на ум только такой приходит.